# \DeclaredPairedDelimiter vs \newcommand

Tags: macros, delimiters

When should I use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and when should I use `\newcommand`?

For example I have defined

```
%Ceiling function
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
%Floor function
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is a very specific command in the `mathtools` package for opening and closing delimiters (e.g. parentheses, brackets, braces) where you want the option to automatically resize them.

For example, it allows you to replace `\lfloor`...`\rfloor` with `\floor{`...`}` and `\left\lfloor`...`\right\rfloor` with `\floor*{`...`}`.

Other common examples are:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\paren{(}{)}           % (parentheses)
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ang{\langle}{\rangle} % <angle brackets>
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}   % |absolute value|
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}  % ||norm||
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bkt{[}{]}             % [brackets]
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set{\{}{\}}           % {braces}
```

As in the other example, I get commands that have fixed size, or that scale with the expression. See the [`mathtools` documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf) for more information about this command.

`\newcommand`, however, is much more general, allowing for a much broader class of shortcuts. For example, if I'm writing about combinatorics, then I would type `combinatorics` a lot. I could shorten this by writing `\newcommand{\cbs}{combinatorics}`, and then whenever I type `\cbs` in the document, it's expanded out to `combinatorics`. There's no need to relate it to delimiters. [1]

You can also declare commands with arguments: for example, `\newcommand{\dfr}[2]{d #1/d #2}` defines a command for derivatives; then, I can call `\dfr{f}{x}` to get *df*/*dx* and `\dfr{f}{y}` to get *df*/*dy*. See [the Wikibooks page on macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands) for more information.

You can use `\newcommand` to make delimiters, e.g. `\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}`, though then you don't get both a version that scales and one that doesn't. The point is that *`\newcommand` is so much more general than `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, but doesn't handle scaling automatically*.

Finally, for, "is this the best way to do it?" I would say that since you want to use the functionality that `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` offers, you may as well use it, so yes, you're doing it right.

---

[1]: A more useful example would be to define a `\newcommand` for something that you might go back and change later. For example, if you have a piece of notation that you use a lot but haven't finalized, defining a `\newcommand` for it means when you change it, you only have to change it once. For example, in definitions, I italicize the word being defined, so I can use `\newcommand{\term}[1]{\textit{#1}}` and then call `\term{word being defined}`. Then, if later on I decide I want to underline definitions, all I have to do is update the `\newcommand` in a single place in the document.

Comment: I hope you mean `\newcommand{\term}{\textit}`, as you use it like `\term{word being defined}`.

Comment: The macro `\itshape` is a switch and doesn't take an argument. Thus, you should define the `\term`macro as follows: `\newcommand{\term}[1]{{\itshape #1}}`. (Note the extra pair of curly braces that limits the scope of `\itshape`.) A shortcoming (flaw?) of this definition is that one doesn't get an automatic italics correction at the end of the argument of `\term`. Thus, it's better to define the macro via `\newcommand{\term}[1]{\textit{#1}}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke and Mico: whoops, I ought to have known that. Thank you for your corrections; I have edited my post to fix it.